# PHP Formatting URL within a Form Action

Tags: php

I would like to add the ID of a User to the form action as a `URL`.

For Example `view_member.php?id=2`

Can somebody possible show me the correct way to format PHP code in the form action below where I can include the id as `$recptid`

```
$recptid = $_GET['id'];
```

I have tried

```
<form action="<?phpview_member.php?id=$recptid?>" method="post">
```

I would like to be able to add a link  but my formatting is wrong

```
// insert php code as URL in the form action the a submit is pressed
<form action="<?php?>" method="post">

</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<form action="<?php echo "view_member.php?id=".$recptid; ?>" method="post">
```

i hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thank You , Thats the correct way . Cheers . I will accept as answered in 7 mins